# Is there a function in Android like onShow in MFC for layout

Tags: android, layout

i have a tabbed layout with 2 tabs, every tab has it's own view. I search for a function that can overwritten that is called every time if i click on a tab to show the layout.

Thanks in advance...

Hasan Caliskan

EDIT:

thanks for you answers, but it doesn't work...

```
onWindowVisibilityChanged
```

is called one time if i start my app.

```
onFocusChanged
```

function is never called ???

Or i'm doing something wrong ?
Here is the code i've implemented...

```
protected void onWindowVisibilityChanged(int a)
{
    int c = 0;

    c+= 1;
}

protected void onFocusChanged(boolean b, int i , Rect rec)
{
    int c = 0;

    c += 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
   I hope you have two tabs namely main and sub, when you cliked main tab, a view has to be open and similarly when you clikced sub tab , another view has to be opened.am i right

Comment: Yes, that's the way i'm trying to show the layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
          Then you can use tabchanged event as shown below

tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setContent(
                R.id.content_movies).setIndicator("",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_article)));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setContent(
                new Intent(this, BS_Bars.class)).setIndicator("",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_bar)));
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
        Bundle b=new Bundle();

         if(arg0.equals("tab1"))
        {

       // write the code here to show the view


        }

        else if (arg0.equals("tab2")) {

                 // write the code here to show the view 
       }
      });
```

Comment: Thank for the code snippet, i have to go know :( i'm try this later and post if this works. Thanks again...

Comment: @Hasan Caliskan:To gain reputation, and make others to answer your question, vote it and accepts the good answers of your questions

Answer (score 0):

How about overriding

```
onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus)
```

Called when the window containing this view gains or loses focus.

Edit: Try

```
onFocusChanged(boolean, int, Rect) or onWindowVisibilityChanged(int)
```

Comment: Hi, i had tried this, but the function doesn't called if i switch between the tabs. This function is only called if i leave my app. Is there are no function like onShow in MFC ???